# Voicemail forwarding numbers - Tmo prepaid plan

Tags: voicemail, t-mobile

I switched a monthly Tmobile plan several months ago and absolutely hate the voicemail "service".  I previously had all my VM's sent to my email via YouMail (kind of like Google Voice).

Today while looking through settings I noticed there are three Voicemail Forwarding numbers in the Phone Settings menu.  Each for a different scenario (busy, unavailable, unreachable).  All numbers are currently set to Tmobile's VM handling number.

Has anyone with a TMobile monthly plan had success in changing these numbers to use a third party VM service such as Google Voice or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the suggestion of a forum member elsewhere, I called TMobile and asked them about their new "uncarrier" plan.  It is a non-contract, postpaid plan with the exact same pricing and services as my current TMo prepaid plan, but I regain the ability to forward voicemails among other things.   You have to submit to a credit check for a possible deposit (max is only one month's plan ie $50).

So going to the "uncarrier" plan was the solution for me.  Hope this helps.